# IPC between Linux and Windows processes

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql, oracle, informix

How can one database hosted in windows system be accessed and queryed by a Linux's process ?
I have a web application with mysql and I am going to have to create a database in Linux then I need an application to access [inner join] tables in the database in windows with the one in Linux.

A project manager in my company is having an idea to send messages to yahoo messenger using server script and mysql database data. The messages are stored in a table and are fired on particular setup date. She uses the library made for Linux system to send the message (IPC type). I am kinda messed up wondering if this is actually feasible.

I conclude the guy actully doesn't know what is IPC and just trys messing a usual library with messenger. or is it me ? Your ideas and explanation are what I will fight on Monday talks, I love mouth fights!

I bet he is using this http://labs.gree.jp/Top/OpenSource/DBus-en.html

???????????

Comment: Most databases comes with libraries/data base drivers for your OS, that can access that database no matter what OS and server the database itself is running on. But if your question is actually how to do an SQL inner join on 2 MySQL databases, you have a different problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q: IPC between Linux and Windows processes

A: Your best bet is probably either 1) sockets (if feasible), or 2) Web services

> Q: A project manager in my company is having an idea to send messages
>   to yahoo messenger using server script and mysql database data.

Q: What has he/she been smoking?  Does the team get to share a toke or two?

> Q: I have a web application with mysql and I am going to have to
>   create a database in Linux then I need an application to access [inner
>   join] tables in the database in windows with the one in Linux.

This is really a separate issue.  If the two servers are co-located on the same LAN, there are various "linkage" options.

Otherwise, I'd just treat the separate databases *as* separate databases and use some kind of web service (WCF might be a good choice on Windows; Tomcat or JBoss on Linux) to "link" the two.

Comment: Q: What has he/she been smoking? Are they sharing with the team?

Thank you for your reply. What does that mean ?

Comment: I update my post to add a new link. It's skype and php IPC communication DBus.

Comment: I figure it out 90% that I don't believe that php skype wrapper works out. I quit.